# Port forwarding through shared wifi

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a router, a laptop that connected to it via wifi, and a PC, connected to my laptop via Ethernet.

How can I make 27015 port (UDP) forwarded on my PC? If I add my laptop's ip (192.168.1.* * *) in my router admin panel then everything is okay, so how can I make the same with PC (ip = 192.168.137. * * *)?

Additional info : asus rt-n14u router; laptop OS: windows 7, pc OS: windows 10

Comment: The same port cannot be forwarded to two different machines. The first rule always applies and all the others are ignored.

Comment: Really, your PC is connected to your laptop via ethernet? This is a very weird setup, you pc shouldnt even participate in the same network than your router this way... Do you really want your laptop to act as routing device and build a secondary network for your PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router-->Laptop-->PC

What you describe looks like you want your windows 7 basically as a bridge. For this, you go to control panel->network adapter settings and select your WLAN and ethernet port, rightlick and select the bridge option.

This way you get

Router-->Laptop
    & PC

This way your PC and Laptop are in the same network, sharing the same gateway and DNS servers.

Her some nice tutorial.

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/bridge-network-connections-in-windows-7-8-10/

One alternative solution could be to get a nice wlan usb adapter for your PC thats around 10-20$...

By the way, routing with NAT is a Windows Server thing, but client OS is not equipped with support for NAT.

Comment: Ok I will try it now, but your last edit, does it mean that I will not be able to do it? >client OS

Comment: As long as you make sure both OS are in the network where your router can forward a port to you can easily do it. There could be a reason for you that you dont want both devices in the same network but it looks like there is no intentional reason. Bridging is easy but multiple routers is hard...

Comment: It worked, I mean, Internet is working, but my PC IP is 192.168.56.1 now. So, I can't forward a port.. :( How can I make my PC have address like 192.168.1.*** ?   Also, my router panel now says that there are two devices on "192.168.1.250".

Comment: Well i guess that means my very last edit applies and you should go for an usb wlan adapter. On the other hand, the last thing that comes to my mind is that you can leave the bridge mode at windows 7 and try to give a static ip like 192.168.1.249 and your router as gateway to your PC. Network mask of course calss C, 255.255.255.0

Comment: Uhh it seems like I tried everything but this garbage still don't work. Yes, I think I'll get wlan adapter and if it won't work then I'll smash this PC.